# ArgumentException was Unhandled(The Parameter is incorrect)

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, unhandled-exception

I am getting the exception **ArgumentException was Unhandled(The Parameter is incorrect)** in wp7 app when i touches the screen. I have already put all break points, but not getting why this exception is coming?Following i am putting the stack trace of that exception. Please help me?

```
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_HitTestPoint(UIElement element, Point ptHit)
   at System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(Point intersectingPoint, UIElement subtree)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureListener.TouchStart()
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureListener.OnTouchFrameReported(Object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.Touch.OnTouch(Object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.RaiseEvent(IntPtr target, UInt32 eventId, IntPtr coreEventArgs, UInt32 eventArgsTypeIndex)
```

Comment: Pleas add more information (application type, UserControls, code, xaml, etc.) to your question, the provided StackTrace is not enough to give you an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem with **Microshoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit**. This is a kind of bug in this library. When I removed all the code of gesture from xaml file then the above exception is not coming. I don't know what's the actual reason behind this.